# How to Add a new JsonArray Property to a Existing Json Property using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I already have a Json value got from calling an API, I want to add a new Json List to the exiting Property, So

```
 #calling some API in a loop Start

        $apijson = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $api -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ConvertFrom-Json
        $response = $apijson| ConvertTo-Json 

        $null = $data.Add($response);

 #calling some API in a loop End
```

My apiJson will look like the below

```
  {
            "host": "tet",
            "port": 443,
            "protocol": "http",
            "isPublic": false,
            "status": "READY",
            "startTime": 1585220081665,
            "testTime": 1585220127003,
            "engineVersion": "2.1.0",
            "criteriaVersion": "2009q",
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "delegation": 1
                }
            ]
        }
```

Now I have a custom new JsonArray

```
[
    {
        "name":  "TLE",
        "Strength":  128
    },
    {
        "name":  "TLS",
        "trength":  415
    }
]
```

I want to add the above JsonArray to my original Json Property which makes a full Json like below

```
{
            "host": "tet",
            "port": 443,
            "protocol": "http",
            "isPublic": false,
            "status": "READY",
            "startTime": 1585220081665,
            "testTime": 1585220127003,
            "engineVersion": "2.1.0",
            "criteriaVersion": "2009q",
            "endpoints": [
                {
                    "delegation": 1
                }
            ]
        },
    "Strength": [
         {
            "name":  "TLE",
            "Strength":  128
          },
        {
           "name":  "TLS",
           "trength":  415
        }
       ]
```

I tried with Addmember, Concatination nothing working unfortunately.

Comment: Do not try to manipulate the Json string, deserialize the json strings, concatenate them and serialize them again: `$api = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $api -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ConvertFrom-Json; $Strength = $JsonArray | ConvertFrom-Json; $api, $Strength | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 5`

Comment: Please, stop calling anything that is returned from `ConvertFrom-Json` **Json** (like `$apijson`) as it no longer Json but an general object. I suspect that you also confusing yourself in this matter...

Comment: @iRon thanks for the clarification now i understood what you are actually referring to. I just did the conversation and reconversion again and again unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for when you are adding `Strength` as a property to an existing single object (converted from JSON). When using `Add-Member`, you need to force your new object to be a single array object.

```
$apijson = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $api -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | ConvertFrom-Json
$newjson = @'
[
    {
        "name":  "TLE",
        "Strength":  128
    },
    {
        "name":  "TLS",
        "trength":  415
    }
]
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json
$apijson | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name 'Strength' -Value @($newjson)
$apijson | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```